# fixed-data-table: Error occured when triggering an event in cellRenderer in Fixed-data-table(Facebook-data-table)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I'm using Fixed-data-table in my react app.I'm new to this concept Fixed-data-table.Facing the problem with calling a function in cellRenderer fires an event.In that i'm triggering an function by onClick event but i got an error **Uncaught TypeError: r.openDeletePopUp is not a function** Help me out to solve this issue.
Here is my code, Please have a look

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import 'fixed-data-table/dist/fixed-data-table.css';


ButtonDelete(cellData, cellDataKey, rowData, rowIndex){
var _id=(JSON.stringify(rowData._id)).replace(/\"/g, "");
var isDelete=(JSON.stringify(rowData.isDelete)).replace(/\"/g, "");

return(
  <span className="btn btn-primary btnDel" type="button"  style={{marginLeft: 10}} onClick={() => this.openDeletePopUp(_id, isDelete)}>
    <span style={{fontFamily: 'verdana',fontSize: 12}} >DELETE</span>
  </span>
)
}

openDeletePopUp(_id,value){

$('#OpenDeleteComment').modal('show');
}


<Table
  rowHeight={75}
  headerHeight={50}
  rowGetter={(rowIndex) => {
        return this.state.categories[rowIndex]
      }}
  rowsCount={this.state.categories.length}
  width={1500}
  height={500}
  {...this.props}>
  <Column
  label="Icon"
    cellRenderer= {this.Images}
    fixed={true}
    width={75}
  />
  <Column
    label={this.state.type+"name"}
    cellRenderer= {this.name}
    fixed={true}
    width={500}
  />
  <Column
    label="Created"
    cellRenderer= {this.created}
    fixed={true}
    width={130}
  />
  <Column
    cellRenderer= {this.ButtonEdit}
    fixed={true}
    width={130}
  />
  <Column
    cellRenderer= {this.ButtonDelete}
    fixed={true}
    width={130}
  />

</Table>
```

Thanks in advance